# BigQuery timestamp_trunc not applying timezone

Tags: google-bigquery

According to [Google BigQuery's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_trunc) this is how to apply timezones to timestamp_trunc:

```
SELECT
  timestamp_value AS timestamp_value,
  TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(timestamp_value, WEEK(MONDAY), "UTC") AS utc_truncated,
  TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(timestamp_value, WEEK(MONDAY), "Pacific/Auckland") AS nzdt_truncated
FROM (SELECT TIMESTAMP("2017-11-06 00:00:00+12") AS timestamp_value);

-- Display of results may differ, depending upon the environment and time zone where this query was executed.
+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| timestamp_value         | utc_truncated           | nzdt_truncated          |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2017-11-05 12:00:00 UTC | 2017-10-30 00:00:00 UTC | 2017-11-05 11:00:00 UTC |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

I ran this (my timestamp column is a 'timestamp' type and my data is in UTC-0):

```
select TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(timestamp, MINUTE) as timestamp
,TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(timestamp, MINUTE, "America/New_York") as ny_timestamp
from table
```

And got the same value in both columns.

The documentation claims to support timezones on minute truncation but it doesn't appear to be converting my timestamp to the right zone.

If you know what I'm doing incorrectly, please let me know. I'm stumped. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like an unexpected behavior of [TIMESTAMP_TRUNC](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_trunc). Based from the test I made timezone conversion does not work at `HOUR` and `MINUTE`. I created a [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/220066746) for this.

In the meantime you can convert the timezone before truncating. See query below:

```
WITH CTE as (
    SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as test_time
)

SELECT 
  TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(test_time, MINUTE) as utc_timestamp
  ,TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP(DATETIME(test_time, "America/New_York")), MINUTE) as ny_timestamp
FROM CTE
```

Output:

[image]